# What are the direct download links for iOS 7.0?

Tags: ios, ipsw

Direct download (i.e. from Apple servers) links for officially-released iOS firmware versions through 6.1.4 are listed here, with checksums:

http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Firmware

These firmware images can be used to do a restore within iTunes (<kbd>option</kbd>-click the "Restore" button) without downloading the firmware via iTunes, e.g. if you have several devices to restore on different computers or if the computer running iTunes is not as well-connected as another available computer.

What, if they exist, are the direct download links for iOS 7.0?

Comment: (FWIW, The iPhone Wiki has added the 7.0 downloads)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the direct download links for .ipsw files from  [Redmond Pie's very helpful post](http://www.redmondpie.com/download-ios-7-final-ipsw-for-iphone-5-4s-4-ipad-and-ipod-touch-direct-links/).

The links below are for build 11A465 of iOS 7.0:

- [iPad (4th generation CDMA)](http://appldnld.apple.com/iOS7/091-9461.20130918.Bqjnt/iPad3,6_7.0_11A465_Restore.ipsw)
- [iPad (4th generation GSM)](http://appldnld.apple.com/iOS7/091-9479.20130918.grt5t/iPad3,5_7.0_11A465_Restore.ipsw)
- [iPad (4th generation Wi-Fi)](http://appldnld.apple.com/iOS7/091-9465.20130918.OBH6T/iPad3,4_7.0_11A465_Restore.ipsw)
- [iPad mini (CDMA)](http://appldnld.apple.com/iOS7/091-9460.20130918.re34f/iPad2,7_7.0_11A465_Restore.ipsw)
- [iPad mini (GSM)](http://appldnld.apple.com/iOS7/091-9470.20130918.vvn4r/iPad2,6_7.0_11A465_Restore.ipsw)
- [iPad mini (Wi-Fi)](http://appldnld.apple.com/iOS7/091-9466.20130918.F9UYG/iPad2,5_7.0_11A465_Restore.ipsw)
- [iPad 3 Wi-Fi (3rd generation)](http://appldnld.apple.com/iOS7/091-9480.20130918.Qvy54/iPad3,1_7.0_11A465_Restore.ipsw)
- [iPad 3 Wi-Fi + Cellular (CDMA)](http://appldnld.apple.com/iOS7/091-9467.20130918.GT54R/iPad3,2_7.0_11A465_Restore.ipsw)
- [iPad 3 Wi-Fi + Cellular (GSM)](http://appldnld.apple.com/iOS7/091-9483.20130918.AOc12/iPad3,3_7.0_11A465_Restore.ipsw)
- [iPad 2 Wi-Fi (Rev A)](http://appldnld.apple.com/iOS7/091-9487.20130918.u45rf/iPad2,4_7.0_11A465_Restore.ipsw)
- [iPad 2 Wi-Fi](http://appldnld.apple.com/iOS7/091-9464.20130918.jozAF/iPad2,1_7.0_11A465_Restore.ipsw)
- [iPad 2 Wi-Fi + 3G (GSM)](http://appldnld.apple.com/iOS7/091-9472.20130918.Ew3Qs/iPad2,2_7.0_11A465_Restore.ipsw)
- [iPad 2 Wi-Fi + 3G (CDMA)](http://appldnld.apple.com/iOS7/091-9471.20130918.Sin12/iPad2,3_7.0_11A465_Restore.ipsw)
- [iPhone 5 (CDMA)](http://appldnld.apple.com/iOS7/091-9475.20130918.9Fu45/iPhone5,2_7.0_11A465_Restore.ipsw)
- [iPhone 5 (GSM)](http://appldnld.apple.com/iOS7/091-9495.20130918.FuFu4/iPhone5,1_7.0_11A465_Restore.ipsw)
- [iPhone 4s](http://appldnld.apple.com/iOS7/091-9486.20130918.V5WIX/iPhone4,1_7.0_11A465_Restore.ipsw)
- [iPhone 4 (GSM Rev A)](http://appldnld.apple.com/iOS7/091-9469.20130918.XXW3g/iPhone3,2_7.0_11A465_Restore.ipsw)
- [iPhone 4 (GSM)](http://appldnld.apple.com/iOS7/091-9485.20130918.Xa98u/iPhone3,1_7.0_11A465_Restore.ipsw)
- [iPhone 4 (CDMA)](http://appldnld.apple.com/iOS7/091-9459.20130918.Fre43/iPhone3,3_7.0_11A465_Restore.ipsw)
- [iPod touch (5th generation)](http://appldnld.apple.com/iOS7/091-9476.20130918.jVRTr/iPod5,1_7.0_11A465_Restore.ipsw)

Should you be a reviewer or get lucky with an early delivery, the 5c and 5s firmware update - build 11A470a of iOS 7.0.1 are below courtesy of an [article by Mike Webb on mobilespie](http://www.mobilespie.com/5507/ios-7-0-1-iphone-5c-5s-download/):

- [iPhone 5c (?CDMA)](http://appldnld.apple.com/iOS7/031-0289.20130914.DoOPv/iPhone5,3_7.0.1_11A470a_Restore.ipsw)
- [iPhone 5c (?GSM)](http://appldnld.apple.com/iOS7/031-0292.20130914.rHLcE/iPhone5,4_7.0.1_11A470a_Restore.ipsw)
- [iPhone 5s (?CDMA)](http://appldnld.apple.com/iOS7/031-0290.20130914.khyTp/iPhone6,1_7.0.1_11A470a_Restore.ipsw)
- [iPhone 5s (?GSM)](http://appldnld.apple.com/iOS7/031-0286.20130914.oNmiv/iPhone6,2_7.0.1_11A470a_Restore.ipsw)

*Also, I'd kindly remind people to not be greedy - downloading all the builds means someone else looking for one build might be prevented from getting a download.*

Comment: @bmike, much obliged. :-)

Comment: If someone wants to edit these links if they find any errors, I'd be appreciative. The descriptions of ATT/VZW should probably be changed to match the hardware model numbers too. http://www.apple.com/ipad/LTE/ and http://www.apple.com/iphone/LTE/

Comment: I can at least verify the iPhone 4S link is correct.

Comment: The links were working about 10 minutes ago but as of this writing all of the links above are broken. Apple caught on...

Comment: Which one? The ones I clicked still work.

Comment: It's also possible that the content delivery network is being updated or the web servers are just incapable of answering all the requests coming in. My experience in the past is that these links are durable and errors are capacity issues. But, time will tell if they get changed by Apple to prevent this.

Comment: Remember, to use the files place them in `~/Library/iTunes/iTunes Software Updates/`

Answer (score 0):

If you need firmware for older devices, you can get them from http://iosindex.com/ios-firmware

List of iOS Firmware

Lost of them, just a sample below. Use the one fitting your device model.

[image: firmware]