# Where can I find information about past versions of iOS and code-signing windows?

Tags: ios, upgrade

I have an iPad 2 that is currently running iOS 5.0.1. I'm generally happy with it but some applications require a more recent iOS version. So I started to look into upgrading it, but the only upgrade that it offers is to iOS 7.

From the look of it I don't like the new design of iOS 7 too much and also upgrading to a version this fresh doesn't appeal to me. So my question is: is there a way to upgrade to some version of iOS 5.x or iOS 6.x instead of upgrading to iOS 7?

Comment: What is the current Baseband of your device? It is under `Settings > General > About > Modem Firmware`.Also, what is the model of your iPad?

Look at the back of your iPad. Down towards the center bottom you’ll see the word iPad, and below it the amount of storage space it has (16,32, or 64GB). Below that you’ll see some fine print about the iPad. The first line begins with ‘Designed by Apple in California.’ At the end of that line you’ll see ‘Model’ and a 5 character model number beginning with the letter ‘A’. For example, my iPad is Model A1430 – an iPad 3rd gen 64GB WiFi + Cellular model.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently, no, your only option is to upgrade to iOS 7. This is because [Apple is no longer signing iOS 6](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2013/09/21/apple-not-signing-ios-6-1-34/) and the [firmware signing status for iPad 2](http://www.icj.me/ios/all#iPad21) shows iOS 7 as the only signed version.

[image: iPad 2 Apple Signing Status]

#### **Note: Lookup the signing status (or get the direct download links) for [all iOS versions here](http://www.icj.me/ios/all).**

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to check out [this website](http://www.iphonefirmware.com/firmwares-download/), which has all past iOS updates. Scroll down and click the iPad 2 model you have (Wifi, GSM, CDMA). Then, simply choose the iOS you want (probably 6.1.3). It will download an `.ipsw` file.

[image]

Then, in iTunes, plug in your iPad. Now, here's the important part: Press <kbd>Option/Shift</kbd> while clicking the `Check for Update` button. A dialog box should open up, and you should navigate to the `.ipsw` file and then click it. Similarly, if, for some reason, you want to restore your iPad and update, press <kbd>Option/Shift</kbd> while clicking the `Restore` button.

Comment: How does these ipsw get signed so iTunes will actually install them?

Comment: I believe that they are already signed by Apple. According to [this link](http://osxdaily.com/2010/11/23/how-to-use-ipsw-files/), you can use a single `.ipsw` file for an infinite amount of users.

Comment: FWIW - Friday, you could have downloaded iOS 6.1.3 for iPad 2 and Apple would have signed it at the time you restored and all would work. Today, no signing of iOS 6 for iPad 2 and newer...

Comment: Apple won't sign anything below iOS7 for your iPad anymore. They removed it. I will look into a possible second scenario that may be able to rectify the situation for you.

Comment: Yes, I realize that this answer is not useful, but I am keeping it as just a reference for others. The correct answer has already been accepted.