# Can I still Downgrade my iPhone 4 down to IOS 6.1.3 from IOS 7?

Tags: ios, iphone

I just wanted to know if there is still a way to downgrade iOS 7, i don't have beta. (on an iPhone 4 which is listed as iPhone3,1 on http://iossupportmatrix.com).

Comment: Before we close / merge this - let's see if there's any truth to the various reports on the internet about Apple still signing the iOS 6.1.3 build for the iPhone 4 hardware. I don't think there's credible evidence that 4s or iPad 3 or other hardware can downgrade, but I'd hate to miss a change to help someone with iPhone 4 by lumping everything together too soon.

Comment: I also wish there were an http://iossupportmatrix.com for what versions of IPSW Apple is currently signing.

Comment: This should be closed as a duplicate. This page - http://www.icj.me/ios/all - that I had mentioned in [my answer here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/102783/31743), has the signing status for all Apple devices and firmware versions. Currently iOS 7 is the only signed version for all iPhone 4 variants.

Comment: @MK You are not only right, but awesome for posting the details here. I wish I had seen / absorbed what you had posted earlier. I retract my call for details and can help with consolidating answers if needed. In addition to the duplicate, we have this related thread: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102928/downgrading-to-a-previous-ios-version

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no officially sanctioned way to downgrade. If you had been using the beta, it would have been possible; however, the official release is not reversible.